# Is this auth/login procedure safe?

Tags: php, security, session, authentication, kohana

Is this technique safe enough? Could I trust to sessions like this? Or should I add something?

**Auth -module**

```
class Auth {

    public function login($user, $pass, $random_unique_salt)
    {
        if ($this->_bcrypt($pass, $random_unique_salt) === 'correct password hash') // etc.
        {
            // Success...
            $session = Session::instance();
            $session->set('login', TRUE);
            $session->regenerate();
        }
    }
}
```

**Base -controller**

```
class Controller_Base extends Controller {

    protected $_login = FALSE;

    public function before()
    {
        $this->_login = Session::instance()->get('login', FALSE);
    }
}
```

**Members only -controller**

```
class Controller_Membersonly extends Controller_Base {

    public function action_index()
    {
        if ($this->_login === TRUE)
        {
            // Success...
            echo 'Show (safely?) some secrets.';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Slightly OT, but it looks like your password hashing scheme doesn't use a salt. And what hash are you using? Some plain md5/sha-x, or a function designed for password hashed, such as bcrypt?

Comment: That's just a random example, that's why there's comment // etc. Bcrypt is way to go.

Comment: Good :) Btw I recommend dropping one of your tags in favor of a "php" tag. Some of the people who can answer this might have "php" as a favorite tag, but not any of yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This technique is safe enough. I could trust sessions like this.

Answer (score 1):

The only vulnerability I see is [CWE-706 - Use of one way has with a predictable salt](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/760.html).  Each password needs to have its own unique salt.   bcrypt isn't a  bad password hashing method because it cannot be efficiently implemented on a GPU or FPGA.

The code style is a bit paranoid,  not a bad thing.  Your comparison operators are a bit excessive.  Make sure you read up on [fuzzy typing in php](http://www.blueshoes.org/en/developer/php_cheat_sheet) so you don't make a mistake in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your input! This code example isn't complete. $random_unique_salt refers to unpredictable salt.

Comment: @stacknoob yeah but it has to be unique for each password,  it should be a parameter to the login function.

Comment: It's possible to generate unique salt for each password in login -method too, but it make sense to add __$random_unique_salt__ to parameters, because salt generator isn't implemented in this example.